# Get last Friday and Get next Thursday

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, date-arithmetic

I created a code to get the last friday, but it will only work if today is already the next week.

```
        iWeekday = Weekday(Now(), vbFriday)
        LastFridayDate = Now - (iWeekday - 1)
```

I need a code to get the last friday based on today's date, and get the next thursday.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean on a Friday you want the date of Friday the previous week? For that you simply need to base `iWeekday` on Saturdays.

```
LastFridayDate = Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)
```

For calculating next Thursday you need to subtract the weekday number based on Thursday from 8 and add that to the current date:

```
NextThursdayDate = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbThursday)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> For i = 0 to 8 : _
  d1 = Date + i : _
  d2 = d1 - Weekday(d1, vbSaturday) : _
  WScript.Echo WeekdayName(Weekday(d1), True) & ", " & d1 & "  ->  " _
    & Weekdayname(Weekday(d2), True) & ", " & d2 : _
Next
Do, 27.02.2014  ->  Fr, 21.02.2014
Fr, 28.02.2014  ->  Fr, 21.02.2014
Sa, 01.03.2014  ->  Fr, 28.02.2014
So, 02.03.2014  ->  Fr, 28.02.2014
Mo, 03.03.2014  ->  Fr, 28.02.2014
Di, 04.03.2014  ->  Fr, 28.02.2014
Mi, 05.03.2014  ->  Fr, 28.02.2014
Do, 06.03.2014  ->  Fr, 28.02.2014
Fr, 07.03.2014  ->  Fr, 28.02.2014
>>> For i = 0 to 8 : _
  d1 = Date + i : _
  d2 = d1 + 8 - Weekday(d1, vbThursday) : _
  WScript.Echo WeekdayName(Weekday(d1), True) & ", " & d1 & "  ->  " _
    & Weekdayname(Weekday(d2), True) & ", " & d2 : _
Next
Do, 27.02.2014  ->  Do, 06.03.2014
Fr, 28.02.2014  ->  Do, 06.03.2014
Sa, 01.03.2014  ->  Do, 06.03.2014
So, 02.03.2014  ->  Do, 06.03.2014
Mo, 03.03.2014  ->  Do, 06.03.2014
Di, 04.03.2014  ->  Do, 06.03.2014
Mi, 05.03.2014  ->  Do, 06.03.2014
Do, 06.03.2014  ->  Do, 13.03.2014
Fr, 07.03.2014  ->  Do, 13.03.2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Here yah go.

```
Dim x1, lFriday, lFri : x1 = 1
Dim x2, nThursday, nThur : x2 = 1
Dim c

Do While lFriday <> 6
c = DateAdd("d", -x1, Now()):lFriday = Weekday(c): lFri = c : x1 = x1 + 1
Loop


Do While nThursday <> 5
c = DateAdd("d", x2, Now()):nThursday = Weekday(c): nThur = c : x2 = x2 + 1
Loop
response.write("Last Friday = " & lFri)
response.write("Next Thursday = " & nThur)
'Last Friday = lFri 
'Next Thursday = nThur
```

Comment: Thanks #TechnologRich, but #Ansgar Wiechers code are simpler.

Comment: Glad you got your answer!